# Setting Colors in ~/.bashrc [CentOS 7]

Tags: terminal, colors, bashrc

I'm trying to set colors within my `.bashrc`. I would like my background to be black, bash prompt text to be white and input text to be lime green.
I have this so far:

```
export PS1="[\e[1;37;40m[\u@\W]\$ "
```

however I am unable to change my input text to lime green.

Answer (score 0):

It really looks best if you set your terminal to green foreground and black background and don't modify the prompt to a green foreground color. I don't know the color code for lime green, so I used green.

```
# terminal with green foreground, black background
# no need to set green foreground/background color
export PS1="\e[1;37m[\u@\W]\$ \e[0m"

# terminal with white foreground, black background
#            or black foreground, white background
export PS1="\e[1;37;40m[\u@\W]\$\e[0;32m "
```

Used codes:

- `\e[1m` bold
- `\e[32m` green foreground
- `\e[37m` white foreground
- `\e[40m` black background
- `\e[0m` end sequence

You can also try `\e[92m` light green...

[image: bash color prompt]